# How to get the minimum cost of disconnecting some node from each other in a graph

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

In a given graph, i want to calculate the minimum cost of disconnecting some node from each other in a graph. Example: 
[image] In this graph, let say i want to disconnect `node A`, `node C` and `node F` with each other by removing some edges among these nodes. i.e. by removing `edge A-B` and `edge F-E`, the nodes `A`, `C` and `F` will be disconnected. Here cost means the length of the edge which is being removed. in this example total minimum cost for disconnecting `Node A`, `Node C` and `Node F` from each other is 2+1=3.

Can somebody provide some hint. I am unable to categorize this problem, whether this is a kind of `shortest path problem` or `minimum spanning tree problem`?

Comment: i think, the only way to do it - brute-force search.

Comment: @Anton: Please don't say that :( . I can't imagine my life with brute-force.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called the **multiterminal cut problem**. Unfortunately there seems not to be a Wikipedia entry. The problem is, given a weighted graph and a subset of vertices called the *terminals*, compute the minimum-weight set of edges whose removal disconnects every pair of terminals. The bad news is that this problem is NP-hard, so if you really need an optimal solution on an instance that can't be brute forced, you'll probably have to turn to integer programming. The good news is that there's a simple 2-approximation algorithm (not the best factor known, but you may have to brush up on your linear programming and read the research literature to use the "better" ones), which can be achieved by taking the union of s-t cuts separating each terminal from the others.

Comment: Karger's algorithm won't work here, since it gives (hopefully) the global cut rather than a cut separating two particular vertices.

Comment: SO from where should i start?

Comment: Well, that depends on how large your instances are and how badly you want an optimal solution.

Comment: My graph is a large graph, having at max 100,000 nodes.

Comment: That's a very large instance, so I would suggest that you approximate. The complicated part is computing s-t max flows/min cuts. Andrew V. Goldberg has an efficient implementation of his push-relabel algorithm, but it's written in C. I'm not sure if anyone has ported it to Java. The algorithm itself is described in Goldberg's JACM paper with Robert Tarjan, and the heuristics in Cherkassky-Goldberg. The approximation algorithm is due to Dahlhaus et al and is described nicely in the text of Williamson and Shmoys on approximation algorithm.